# How to resend verification code while verifying/updating attribute in aws-amplify/ aws-cognito?

Tags: react-native, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

How to resend verification code while verifying/updating email/phone attribute in `aws-amplify`/ `aws-cognito`, I'm using this code, to verify email/phone:

```
const responce = await Auth.verifyCurrentUserAttributeSubmit("email", confirmationCode)
```

Is there a possibility to resend the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure you already tried this but would calling this method again, asking for a new code, not work for you:

https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html#verifyuserattribute

Comment: Yay, that really helped, I use method verifyCurrentUserAttribute() and it works now, there was no description in the documentation about this method, so it was confusing, after use sent link to verifyUserAttribute(), it all becomes clear, thanks!